# How to return 400 http status code with @NotNull?

Tags: java, validation, jax-rs

I have a method that's receive two parameters: `id` from type Long and `name` from type String. I need to validate if name is not null with @NotNull from 
`javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` and if it is null I need to return the status code http 400.

This is my implementation.

```
@GET
@Path(URI.route)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Response data(@PathParam("id") Long name,
@PathParam("name") @NotNull String name) throws Exception;
```

Currently it's return https status code 500.

Any idea how I do this?

Comment: You could check if `name` is null within the method and then return : `Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)`

Comment: @NicholasK isn't  `Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)`  a `404` instead of `400`?

Comment: You could use `@Valid` but I think it'd require you to use `@POST` instead of `@GET`.

Comment: My bad, I meant `Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST`

Comment: If using `Spring Boot` is an option, go ahead. `@NotNull` is returning 400, which is the correct behavior :)